# Change in_channels of Conv2d but the weight shape of Conv2d doesnt change?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

```
layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=2, kernel_size=(2,2), stride=(2,2))
layer.in_channels=2
print(layer)
print(layer.weight.shape)
```

I am trying to modify the resnet18 in pytorch model for my own work. The defined resnet18 is for RGB images which has 3 channels at the beginning. I want to change it to 1 channel for the grayscale images. However, I found a problem that changing the in_channels parameter couldn't change the weight shape. So the modified model can't run properly. Why the weight will not change accordingly? How can I fix this problem. Here I made a simple example to illustrate the problem.

The output is:

```
Conv2d(2, 2, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
torch.Size([2, 1, 2, 2])
```

As you can see although the in_channels has been changed from 1 to 2, but the weight shape is still 1 for in_channels.

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 7, 7], expected input[2, 1, 224, 224] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead
```

This was what console presented when I modified the in_channels of conv1 resnet18
from 3 to 1. As I said, I think this was due to the weight shape didn't change accordingly.

Comment: This is interesting. Have you manually overwritten with `Parameter` or else?

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the weight of the layer itself.

```
layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=2, kernel_size=(2,2), stride=(2,2))
layer.in_channels=2
layer.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(2,2,2,2))
print(layer)
print(layer.weight.shape)
```

Output:

```
Conv2d(2, 2, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
torch.Size([2, 2, 2, 2])
```